# Yii2 Menu Bar Visibility to a Specific User

Tags: php, menu, navbar, yii2

In my `main.php`, I have a menu:

```
'items' => [
    ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
    ['label' => 'Biz Staff', 'url' => ['bizstaff/index'], 'visible' => User::isBizAdmin(), 'items' => [
        ['label' => 'Staff List', 'url' => 'index.php?r=user/index'],
        ['label' => 'Add Staff', 'url' => 'index.php?r=user/create'],
    ]],

    ['label' => 'Transaction', 'url' => ['transactions/index'], 'visible' => User::isBizAdmin() || User::isBizStaff(), 'items' => [
        ['label' => 'Transactions', 'url' => 'index.php?r=transactions/index'],
        ['label' => 'Add Transactions', 'url' => 'index.php?r=transactions/create'],
    ]],

    Yii::$app->user->isGuest ?
        ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']] :
        ['label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
          'url' => ['/site/logout'],
          'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']
        ],
    ],
```

Here, I am logged in as the **superadmin** (note that only *Home* and *Logout* menu is visible to *superadmin* user). Inside the homepage (Home menu) is a *List of Biz Admins* which is placed inside a `GridView` widget. It has an *Action* column where *view, update and delete icons* are placed. When I click the view icon of a specific Biz Admin, it will then render a detailed view page of that Biz Admin where its **Store Name** and **List of Staff** are seen. In this page, there is a **View Store** button which will redirect to the `bizadmin` view/page.

Whenever *superadmin* lands on `bizadmin` view/page, the menu bar should now change to:

> Home, Biz Staff, Transaction, Logout

How do I do this? Is it set in the `visible` attribute? 
Any of your answers would be highly appreciated. I am currently stuck in this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You should use `visible` property. `'visible' => true` or `'visible' => false`.

Or you may assemble an array. Like that:

```
NavBar::begin([
                'brandLabel' => 'My Company',
                'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
                'options' => [
                    'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
                ],
            ]);
            $menuItems = [
                ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
                ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
                ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
            ];
            if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
                $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Signup', 'url' => ['/site/signup']];
                $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']];
            } else {
                $menuItems[] = [
                    'label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                    'url' => ['/site/logout'],
                    'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']
                ];
            }
            echo Nav::widget([
                'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
                'items' => $menuItems,
            ]);
            NavBar::end();
```

See in Advanced template - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/views/layouts/main.php

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `Yii::$app->controller->action->id` or `Yii::$app->controller->id` to render menus based on your path.

```
NavBar::begin([
            'brandLabel' => 'My Company',
            'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
            'options' => [
                'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
            ],
        ]);
        $menuItems = [
            ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
            ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
            ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
        ];
        if (Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'put your id here') {
            $menuItems[] = ['render your menu here'];
        } else {
            'do something here'
        }
        echo Nav::widget([
            'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
            'items' => $menuItems,
        ]);
        NavBar::end();
```